# Why does Excel think CSV files are SYLK?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Why does Excel think CSV files are SYLK?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your file probably starts with `ID;` or something similar.

If the first two characters of the file are uppercase `ID` Excel assumes it's an [SYLK file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYmbolic_LinK_%28SYLK%29) type. If you want to keep the column name you can make the characters lower case or insert an apostrophe, `'`, as first character in a text editor before opening in Excel.

The problem goes back to [at least Office 2003](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323626) and is still present in Office 2013.

Comment: Yep, that was it.

Comment: What an awful format specification. I've got a .csv file that begins with "IDNUM," and Excel isn't smart enough to read it as a CSV? Oy.

Comment: I find that Excel is horrible in general when it comes to CSV files.